# Testing render callback in React

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have component which include third-party element with render callback. How best to test this render callback (`renderItem`) with `enzyme` and `jest`?

```
<MyComponent>
  <h3>User List</h3>
  <List 
    renderItem={(key, index) => {
      const { name, isOnline } = users[index];
      const innerText = `${name} (${isOnline ? 'online' : 'offline'})`
      return <div key={key}>{innerText}</div>
    }
  />
</MyComponent>
```

Comment: See if it's rendered?

Comment: @DaveNewton see if it's render correctly. In my situation I have some conditionals, which I want to test too.

Comment: I don't see any conditionals-but like anything else, you'd set them up and see if it's rendered correctly.

Comment: @DaveNewton edited